# ListPlot3D from Data Fortran file

Tags: plotting, graphics, import, fortran, version-5

My .dat file (Fortran) consists of data `(x y u)` as three columns and I would like to plot the variable "u" against the variables "x" and "y" as a surface.
The commands `Import[\path\Bs.dat,"Table"]>>temp`
and then `ListPlot3D[temp]` gives:

> temp is not a rectangular array larger than 2x2

Could anyone point me out?

The link to my file: https://o6uedu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/mahaj67_csis_o6u_edu_eg/Ea5KO8Tt-79JtpSDjN3dVSQB4lXk0NWIsc0EFM8hrRSFtQ?e=ShfwY3

Data inside the file:

```
   1.0000000   1.0000000   0.3775407
   1.0000000   0.9931807   0.3783423
   1.0000000   0.9729086   0.3807292
   1.0000000   0.9397369   0.3846474
   1.0000000   0.8945702   0.3900064
   1.0000000   0.8386408   0.3966794
   1.0000000   0.7734741   0.4045030
   1.0000000   0.7008477   0.4132796
   1.0000000   0.6227427   0.4227800
   1.0000000   0.5412897   0.4327488
   1.0000000   0.4587103   0.4429112
   1.0000000   0.3772572   0.4529822
   1.0000000   0.2991523   0.4626755
   1.0000000   0.2265259   0.4717145
   1.0000000   0.1613592   0.4798410
   1.0000000   0.1054297   0.4868243
   1.0000000   0.0602631   0.4924677
   1.0000000   0.0270914   0.4966136
   1.0000000   0.0068193   0.4991476
   1.0000000   0.0000000   0.5000000
   0.9931807   1.0000000   0.3783423
   0.9931807   0.9931807   0.3791446
   0.9931807   0.9729086   0.3815334
   0.9931807   0.9397369   0.3854547
   0.9931807   0.8945702   0.3908179
   0.9931807   0.8386408   0.3974957
   0.9931807   0.7734741   0.4053246
   0.9931807   0.7008477   0.4141067
   0.9931807   0.6227427   0.4236123
   0.9931807   0.5412897   0.4335860
   0.9931807   0.4587103   0.4437527
   0.9931807   0.3772572   0.4538272
   0.9931807   0.2991523   0.4635233
   0.9931807   0.2265259   0.4725643
   0.9931807   0.1613592   0.4806921
   0.9931807   0.1054297   0.4876762
   0.9931807   0.0602631   0.4933199
   0.9931807   0.0270914   0.4974660
   0.9931807   0.0068193   0.5000000
   0.9931807   0.0000000   0.5008524
   0.9729086   1.0000000   0.3807292
   0.9729086   0.9931807   0.3815334
   0.9729086   0.9729086   0.3839280
   0.9729086   0.9397369   0.3878585
   0.9729086   0.8945702   0.3932337
   0.9729086   0.8386408   0.3999257
   0.9729086   0.7734741   0.4077701
   0.9729086   0.7008477   0.4165680
   0.9729086   0.6227427   0.4260891
   0.9729086   0.5412897   0.4360769
   0.9729086   0.4587103   0.4462561
   0.9729086   0.3772572   0.4563407
   0.9729086   0.2991523   0.4660447
   0.9729086   0.2265259   0.4750913
   0.9729086   0.1613592   0.4832228
   0.9729086   0.1054297   0.4902090
   0.9729086   0.0602631   0.4958536
   0.9729086   0.0270914   0.5000000
   0.9729086   0.0068193   0.5025340
   0.9729086   0.0000000   0.5033864
   0.9397369   1.0000000   0.3846474
   0.9397369   0.9931807   0.3854547
   0.9397369   0.9729086   0.3878585
   0.9397369   0.9397369   0.3918037
   0.9397369   0.8945702   0.3971981
   0.9397369   0.8386408   0.4039126
   0.9397369   0.7734741   0.4117815
   0.9397369   0.7008477   0.4206045
   0.9397369   0.6227427   0.4301498
   0.9397369   0.5412897   0.4401599
   0.9397369   0.4587103   0.4503582
   0.9397369   0.3772572   0.4604585
   0.9397369   0.2991523   0.4701743
   0.9397369   0.2265259   0.4792291
   0.9397369   0.1613592   0.4873657
   0.9397369   0.1054297   0.4943544
   0.9397369   0.0602631   0.5000000
   0.9397369   0.0270914   0.5041464
   0.9397369   0.0068193   0.5066801
   0.9397369   0.0000000   0.5075323
   0.8945702   1.0000000   0.3900064
   0.8945702   0.9931807   0.3908179
   0.8945702   0.9729086   0.3932337
   0.8945702   0.9397369   0.3971981
   0.8945702   0.8945702   0.4026176
   0.8945702   0.8386408   0.4093615
   0.8945702   0.7734741   0.4172623
   0.8945702   0.7008477   0.4261176
   0.8945702   0.6227427   0.4356940
   0.8945702   0.5412897   0.4457321
   0.8945702   0.4587103   0.4559544
   0.8945702   0.3772572   0.4660738
   0.8945702   0.2991523   0.4758036
   0.8945702   0.2265259   0.4848676
   0.8945702   0.1613592   0.4930093
   0.8945702   0.1054297   0.5000000
   0.8945702   0.0602631   0.5056456
   0.8945702   0.0270914   0.5097910
   0.8945702   0.0068193   0.5123238
   0.8945702   0.0000000   0.5131757
   0.8386408   1.0000000   0.3966794
   0.8386408   0.9931807   0.3974957
   0.8386408   0.9729086   0.3999257
   0.8386408   0.9397369   0.4039126
   0.8386408   0.8945702   0.4093615
   0.8386408   0.8386408   0.4161397
   0.8386408   0.7734741   0.4240774
   0.8386408   0.7008477   0.4329699
   0.8386408   0.6227427   0.4425815
   0.8386408   0.5412897   0.4526510
   0.8386408   0.4587103   0.4628994
   0.8386408   0.3772572   0.4730389
   0.8386408   0.2991523   0.4827827
   0.8386408   0.2265259   0.4918549
   0.8386408   0.1613592   0.5000000
   0.8386408   0.1054297   0.5069907
   0.8386408   0.0602631   0.5126343
   0.8386408   0.0270914   0.5167772
   0.8386408   0.0068193   0.5193079
   0.8386408   0.0000000   0.5201590
   0.7734741   1.0000000   0.4045030
   0.7734741   0.9931807   0.4053246
   0.7734741   0.9729086   0.4077701
   0.7734741   0.9397369   0.4117815
   0.7734741   0.8945702   0.4172623
   0.7734741   0.8386408   0.4240774
   0.7734741   0.7734741   0.4320544
   0.7734741   0.7008477   0.4409861
   0.7734741   0.6227427   0.4506343
   0.7734741   0.5412897   0.4607355
   0.7734741   0.4587103   0.4710095
   0.7734741   0.3772572   0.4811675
   0.7734741   0.2991523   0.4909227
   0.7734741   0.2265259   0.5000000
   0.7734741   0.1613592   0.5081451
   0.7734741   0.1054297   0.5151324
   0.7734741   0.0602631   0.5207709
   0.7734741   0.0270914   0.5249087
   0.7734741   0.0068193   0.5274357
   0.7734741   0.0000000   0.5282855
   0.7008477   1.0000000   0.4132796
   0.7008477   0.9931807   0.4141067
   0.7008477   0.9729086   0.4165680
   0.7008477   0.9397369   0.4206045
   0.7008477   0.8945702   0.4261176
   0.7008477   0.8386408   0.4329699
   0.7008477   0.7734741   0.4409861
   0.7008477   0.7008477   0.4499562
   0.7008477   0.6227427   0.4596392
   0.7008477   0.5412897   0.4697697
   0.7008477   0.4587103   0.4800658
   0.7008477   0.3772572   0.4902381
   0.7008477   0.2991523   0.5000000
   0.7008477   0.2265259   0.5090773
   0.7008477   0.1613592   0.5172173
   0.7008477   0.1054297   0.5241964
   0.7008477   0.0602631   0.5298257
   0.7008477   0.0270914   0.5339553
   0.7008477   0.0068193   0.5364767
   0.7008477   0.0000000   0.5373245
   0.6227427   1.0000000   0.4227800
   0.6227427   0.9931807   0.4236123
   0.6227427   0.9729086   0.4260891
   0.6227427   0.9397369   0.4301498
   0.6227427   0.8945702   0.4356940
   0.6227427   0.8386408   0.4425815
   0.6227427   0.7734741   0.4506343
   0.6227427   0.7008477   0.4596392
   0.6227427   0.6227427   0.4693528
   0.6227427   0.5412897   0.4795074
   0.6227427   0.4587103   0.4898198
   0.6227427   0.3772572   0.5000000
   0.6227427   0.2991523   0.5097619
   0.6227427   0.2265259   0.5188325
   0.6227427   0.1613592   0.5269611
   0.6227427   0.1054297   0.5339262
   0.6227427   0.0602631   0.5395415
   0.6227427   0.0270914   0.5436593
   0.6227427   0.0068193   0.5461728
   0.6227427   0.0000000   0.5470178
   0.5412897   1.0000000   0.4327488
   0.5412897   0.9931807   0.4335860
   0.5412897   0.9729086   0.4360769
   0.5412897   0.9397369   0.4401599
   0.5412897   0.8945702   0.4457321
   0.5412897   0.8386408   0.4526510
   0.5412897   0.7734741   0.4607355
   0.5412897   0.7008477   0.4697697
   0.5412897   0.6227427   0.4795074
   0.5412897   0.5412897   0.4896791
   0.5412897   0.4587103   0.5000000
   0.5412897   0.3772572   0.5101802
   0.5412897   0.2991523   0.5199342
   0.5412897   0.2265259   0.5289905
   0.5412897   0.1613592   0.5371006
   0.5412897   0.1054297   0.5440456
   0.5412897   0.0602631   0.5496418
   0.5412897   0.0270914   0.5537439
   0.5412897   0.0068193   0.5562473
   0.5412897   0.0000000   0.5570888
   0.4587103   1.0000000   0.4429112
   0.4587103   0.9931807   0.4437527
   0.4587103   0.9729086   0.4462561
   0.4587103   0.9397369   0.4503582
   0.4587103   0.8945702   0.4559544
   0.4587103   0.8386408   0.4628994
   0.4587103   0.7734741   0.4710095
   0.4587103   0.7008477   0.4800658
   0.4587103   0.6227427   0.4898198
   0.4587103   0.5412897   0.5000000
   0.4587103   0.4587103   0.5103210
   0.4587103   0.3772572   0.5204926
   0.4587103   0.2991523   0.5302303
   0.4587103   0.2265259   0.5392645
   0.4587103   0.1613592   0.5473490
   0.4587103   0.1054297   0.5542679
   0.4587103   0.0602631   0.5598401
   0.4587103   0.0270914   0.5639231
   0.4587103   0.0068193   0.5664140
   0.4587103   0.0000000   0.5672512
   0.3772572   1.0000000   0.4529822
   0.3772572   0.9931807   0.4538272
   0.3772572   0.9729086   0.4563407
   0.3772572   0.9397369   0.4604585
   0.3772572   0.8945702   0.4660738
   0.3772572   0.8386408   0.4730389
   0.3772572   0.7734741   0.4811675
   0.3772572   0.7008477   0.4902381
   0.3772572   0.6227427   0.5000000
   0.3772572   0.5412897   0.5101802
   0.3772572   0.4587103   0.5204926
   0.3772572   0.3772572   0.5306472
   0.3772572   0.2991523   0.5403608
   0.3772572   0.2265259   0.5493658
   0.3772572   0.1613592   0.5574185
   0.3772572   0.1054297   0.5643060
   0.3772572   0.0602631   0.5698502
   0.3772572   0.0270914   0.5739109
   0.3772572   0.0068193   0.5763877
   0.3772572   0.0000000   0.5772200
   0.2991523   1.0000000   0.4626755
   0.2991523   0.9931807   0.4635233
   0.2991523   0.9729086   0.4660447
   0.2991523   0.9397369   0.4701743
   0.2991523   0.8945702   0.4758036
   0.2991523   0.8386408   0.4827827
   0.2991523   0.7734741   0.4909227
   0.2991523   0.7008477   0.5000000
   0.2991523   0.6227427   0.5097619
   0.2991523   0.5412897   0.5199342
   0.2991523   0.4587103   0.5302303
   0.2991523   0.3772572   0.5403608
   0.2991523   0.2991523   0.5500438
   0.2991523   0.2265259   0.5590139
   0.2991523   0.1613592   0.5670301
   0.2991523   0.1054297   0.5738824
   0.2991523   0.0602631   0.5793955
   0.2991523   0.0270914   0.5834320
   0.2991523   0.0068193   0.5858933
   0.2991523   0.0000000   0.5867204
   0.2265259   1.0000000   0.4717145
   0.2265259   0.9931807   0.4725643
   0.2265259   0.9729086   0.4750913
   0.2265259   0.9397369   0.4792291
   0.2265259   0.8945702   0.4848676
   0.2265259   0.8386408   0.4918549
   0.2265259   0.7734741   0.5000000
   0.2265259   0.7008477   0.5090773
   0.2265259   0.6227427   0.5188325
   0.2265259   0.5412897   0.5289905
   0.2265259   0.4587103   0.5392645
   0.2265259   0.3772572   0.5493658
   0.2265259   0.2991523   0.5590139
   0.2265259   0.2265259   0.5679456
   0.2265259   0.1613592   0.5759226
   0.2265259   0.1054297   0.5827377
   0.2265259   0.0602631   0.5882185
   0.2265259   0.0270914   0.5922299
   0.2265259   0.0068193   0.5946754
   0.2265259   0.0000000   0.5954970
   0.1613592   1.0000000   0.4798410
   0.1613592   0.9931807   0.4806921
   0.1613592   0.9729086   0.4832228
   0.1613592   0.9397369   0.4873657
   0.1613592   0.8945702   0.4930093
   0.1613592   0.8386408   0.5000000
   0.1613592   0.7734741   0.5081451
   0.1613592   0.7008477   0.5172173
   0.1613592   0.6227427   0.5269611
   0.1613592   0.5412897   0.5371006
   0.1613592   0.4587103   0.5473490
   0.1613592   0.3772572   0.5574185
   0.1613592   0.2991523   0.5670301
   0.1613592   0.2265259   0.5759226
   0.1613592   0.1613592   0.5838603
   0.1613592   0.1054297   0.5906385
   0.1613592   0.0602631   0.5960874
   0.1613592   0.0270914   0.6000743
   0.1613592   0.0068193   0.6025043
   0.1613592   0.0000000   0.6033206
   0.1054297   1.0000000   0.4868243
   0.1054297   0.9931807   0.4876762
   0.1054297   0.9729086   0.4902090
   0.1054297   0.9397369   0.4943544
   0.1054297   0.8945702   0.5000000
   0.1054297   0.8386408   0.5069907
   0.1054297   0.7734741   0.5151324
   0.1054297   0.7008477   0.5241964
   0.1054297   0.6227427   0.5339262
   0.1054297   0.5412897   0.5440456
   0.1054297   0.4587103   0.5542679
   0.1054297   0.3772572   0.5643060
   0.1054297   0.2991523   0.5738824
   0.1054297   0.2265259   0.5827377
   0.1054297   0.1613592   0.5906385
   0.1054297   0.1054297   0.5973824
   0.1054297   0.0602631   0.6028019
   0.1054297   0.0270914   0.6067663
   0.1054297   0.0068193   0.6091821
   0.1054297   0.0000000   0.6099936
   0.0602631   1.0000000   0.4924677
   0.0602631   0.9931807   0.4933199
   0.0602631   0.9729086   0.4958536
   0.0602631   0.9397369   0.5000000
   0.0602631   0.8945702   0.5056456
   0.0602631   0.8386408   0.5126343
   0.0602631   0.7734741   0.5207709
   0.0602631   0.7008477   0.5298257
   0.0602631   0.6227427   0.5395415
   0.0602631   0.5412897   0.5496418
   0.0602631   0.4587103   0.5598401
   0.0602631   0.3772572   0.5698502
   0.0602631   0.2991523   0.5793955
   0.0602631   0.2265259   0.5882185
   0.0602631   0.1613592   0.5960874
   0.0602631   0.1054297   0.6028019
   0.0602631   0.0602631   0.6081963
   0.0602631   0.0270914   0.6121415
   0.0602631   0.0068193   0.6145453
   0.0602631   0.0000000   0.6153526
   0.0270914   1.0000000   0.4966136
   0.0270914   0.9931807   0.4974660
   0.0270914   0.9729086   0.5000000
   0.0270914   0.9397369   0.5041464
   0.0270914   0.8945702   0.5097910
   0.0270914   0.8386408   0.5167772
   0.0270914   0.7734741   0.5249087
   0.0270914   0.7008477   0.5339553
   0.0270914   0.6227427   0.5436593
   0.0270914   0.5412897   0.5537439
   0.0270914   0.4587103   0.5639231
   0.0270914   0.3772572   0.5739109
   0.0270914   0.2991523   0.5834320
   0.0270914   0.2265259   0.5922299
   0.0270914   0.1613592   0.6000743
   0.0270914   0.1054297   0.6067663
   0.0270914   0.0602631   0.6121415
   0.0270914   0.0270914   0.6160720
   0.0270914   0.0068193   0.6184666
   0.0270914   0.0000000   0.6192708
   0.0068193   1.0000000   0.4991476
   0.0068193   0.9931807   0.5000000
   0.0068193   0.9729086   0.5025340
   0.0068193   0.9397369   0.5066801
   0.0068193   0.8945702   0.5123238
   0.0068193   0.8386408   0.5193079
   0.0068193   0.7734741   0.5274357
   0.0068193   0.7008477   0.5364767
   0.0068193   0.6227427   0.5461728
   0.0068193   0.5412897   0.5562473
   0.0068193   0.4587103   0.5664140
   0.0068193   0.3772572   0.5763877
   0.0068193   0.2991523   0.5858933
   0.0068193   0.2265259   0.5946754
   0.0068193   0.1613592   0.6025043
   0.0068193   0.1054297   0.6091821
   0.0068193   0.0602631   0.6145453
   0.0068193   0.0270914   0.6184666
   0.0068193   0.0068193   0.6208554
   0.0068193   0.0000000   0.6216577
   0.0000000   1.0000000   0.5000000
   0.0000000   0.9931807   0.5008524
   0.0000000   0.9729086   0.5033864
   0.0000000   0.9397369   0.5075323
   0.0000000   0.8945702   0.5131757
   0.0000000   0.8386408   0.5201590
   0.0000000   0.7734741   0.5282855
   0.0000000   0.7008477   0.5373245
   0.0000000   0.6227427   0.5470178
   0.0000000   0.5412897   0.5570888
   0.0000000   0.4587103   0.5672512
   0.0000000   0.3772572   0.5772200
   0.0000000   0.2991523   0.5867204
   0.0000000   0.2265259   0.5954970
   0.0000000   0.1613592   0.6033206
   0.0000000   0.1054297   0.6099936
   0.0000000   0.0602631   0.6153526
   0.0000000   0.0270914   0.6192708
   0.0000000   0.0068193   0.6216577
   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.6224593
```

Thank you.

Very kind wishes,

M.Hajjaj

Comment: Look at what was actually imported and you may see what is wrong.

Comment: To be clear: did you write `temp = Import[....]` and then `ListPlot3D[temp]`? I don’t understand what `Import[...] in temp` Is supposed to mean otherwise. As others have mentioned, please include the *exact* code you used and a sample of your data

Comment: More details are needed. Please share your data. If you don't want to share your data, see what this command says: `Through[{ArrayQ, Dimensions, ResourceFunction["RecordsSummary"]}[temp]]` .

Comment: Thank you for your reply;  I mean "Import["my path\Bs.dat","Table"]>>temp

Answer (score 2):

`Import[\path\Bs.dat,"Table"]>>temp`

reads data from a file **Bs.dat** and writes it to a file named **temp**. To define a symbol `temp` to hold the data for further processing by *Mathematica*, use

`temp=Import[\path\Bs.dat,"Table"]`

instead.

Comment: I have tried to use : temp=Import[] ,but the resulted graph include incorrect dimensions : 0 to 1     ,  1  to 3  and form 1 to 400 that are not consistent with the given data ???

Comment: @MohamedHajjaj You'll have to look at the *Mathematica* representation to see how the numbers from the file are organized into a table. Just type `temp` to see what's in it.

Comment: The temp-file contains ordered pairs {{1., 0.377541},{0.993181, 0.378342},....} not 3d  {x,y,z} as in my file. I do not understand that?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded BS.DAT from the link you provided, then

```
temp = Import["~/Downloads/BS.DAT", "Table"];
ListPlot3D[temp]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is the true graph, I did the same steps, but the result is a wrong graph?

Comment: Sorry, because it is the first time to use this site, if you please help me to upload my graph here?

Comment: Ok--thank you very much for your help, it works now and the the right graph has been generated, the error because of the old version of mathematica-5 and after installation of Mathematica 10, the problem has been solved.

Comment: @MohamedHajjaj Great to hear. Would you mind upvoting/accepting my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since OP mentions he was in version 5, I'd like to talk about how to handle the problem therein.

`ListPlot3D` cannot be used as noticed by OP, because `ListPlot` only handles 2D array at that time. (This is the first syntax in the document of `ListPlot` nowadays BTW. )

I think the most general work-around is to build a `InterpolatingFunction` first and plot with `Plot3D`:

```
func=Interpolation[data]

Plot3D[func[x,y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

[image]

Another possible choice is to use `TriangularSurfacePlot` in the (now obsolete) package `` DiscreteMath`ComputationalGeometry` ``:

```
(* Warning: the following won't work after v5.2 *)
<<DiscreteMath`ComputationalGeometry`

TriangularSurfacePlot[data, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I remember `TriangularSurfacePlot[]`... good times...

Comment: It is a good idea to the solve the problem in Mathematica-5 but I think the interpolation function itself has a degree of error, but it is a solution if the accuracy is not important.

Comment: Ok, the problem has been solved when performed in Mathematica 10 instead of 5. I would like to thank Rohit Namjoshi for his help and also, xzcd for his contribution.

Comment: @MohamedHajjaj Function value of an `InterpolatingFunction` will be exactly the same as the original data at interpolation node. (Try e.g. `func[1,1]`. ) When using in `Plot3D`, you may need to adjust `PlotPoints` option, though.

Comment: Yes you are right